# TaskCanceledException encountered

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I was trying to Update my Local Repository using Git Bash but I'm not able to do the. Even though I made a sync few hours before.

It asked me to enter username and password and even though I type the username and password correct this error stays. I even checked if my username and password is correct or not by logging in to github.com

Below is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if you have [2FA (2 factor authentication)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa) activated.

If you do, then you would need to enter a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) as a password.

If you don't, double-check if you have any special character in your password.

Comment: 2FA is not enabled. And I've already checked the password many time.

Comment: @Kundan What does `git version` return? And `git config credential.helper`? And `env|grep -i proxy`?

Comment: Every command works file except the command which does changes to the repo.

Comment: @Kundan OK but what does those commands return? (`git version`, `git config credential.helper`, `env|grep -i proxy` when done from inside the local repo)

Comment: Thanks for you help @VonC 
I tried revoking all Personal access tokens and Generated new token and used it and now it's working absolutely fine.